# jquery or javascript return tagName on dynamicly added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to get the tagName of some elements that are added dynamically but each time I try that on click I get undefined.I created a simple example that simulates my situation.Here is my code:

```
 <ul>
      <li>sdsa</li>
      <li>dsa</li>

  </ul>
  <button>Press</button>

 $(document).ready(function(){
           var i=0;
           $("button").on("click" , function(){
                $("ul").append("<li>" + i++ + "</li>");
           })

           $("ul").on("click" ,"li" , function(){
               alert($(this).tagName);
           })
       })
```

Each time that I click on the li tags I get undefined.How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this.,.

```
alert($(this).tagName);
```

to this...

```
alert(this.tagName);
```

---

[`tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.tagName) is a property of a DOM Element, not a jQuery object.

Comment: hmm don't know why I tought core dom elements can be applyed to jquery objects thanx

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be the DOM element, not the jQuery object, as tagName is native javascript and not jQuery:

```
this.tagName
```